# Can I connect a drain for my new washing machine to an existing toilet drain?

Tags: toilet, drain

I would like to add a wash machine to the basement.  Near the area of the basement where I'll be adding it is a 4 in drain coming from an upstairs toilet.  Can I tap the new drain into the toilet drain?

Comment: Can you post a picture? It sounds like what you are describing as the "4 in drain from a toilet" is your stack. If so this is fine.

Comment: will need a trap for the washer drain.  Don't forget!

Comment: The trap arm must be properly vented. Don't forget!

Answer (score 1):

You can tap in to the existing stack to drain, the only issue (like bcworkz said above) is you need proper venting. If you were to tap in to that stack without a vent, you could potential pull the water out of any traps above (via suction).

Comment: I would also recommend there be a horizontal run of pipe from the stack at least 18" long before the washer trap, even if properly vented.